# Passage in Seal Script - 18th C Japanese Book of Chinese Poems (Poem identified: 唐・賈至《西亭春望》)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

I recently got an old Japanese Orihon (folding book) which has a lengthy passage in seal script - my assumption was that Japanese seal script would be the same as Chinese seal script, but if I'm wrong about that please correct me!
I managed to translate one title (not pictured) within the book as '將進酒', so given that the book contains a Li Bai poem I'm assuming it may be a collection of Chinese poems.

I know that these things are very hard to translate, so if anyone is able to do it I am very thankful in advance. I don't necessarily need the whole thing translated into English too; just if someone could let me know roughly what it is (e.g a poem, a story, a description etc.).

Thanks,
Thomas.

[image: Seal Script Passage]

Comment: This is the full text of [西亭春望](https://zh.wikisource.org/zh-hant/%E8%A5%BF%E4%BA%AD%E6%98%A5%E6%9C%9B).

Comment: Wow @droooze, thanks for the quick answer! I guess it must be some kind of Chinese poem compilation, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern script:

> **唐　賈至　《西亭春望》**
>
> 日長風暖柳青青　北雁歸飛人窅冥
>
> 岳陽城上聞吹笛　能使春心滿洞庭

With the character variants inserted in their place:

[image]

Comment: Looks like there's an English translation here (https://www.poemhunter.com/best-poems/luo-zhihai/overlooking-in-spring-in-the-western-pavilion/), but it's not great. I'll post it here in case the link dies: Long day, warm wind and green willows / 
Northern geese fly into the gloom / 
On the wall of the Yueyang City someone flutes / 
Full of Dongting with the spring moods

Comment: @user3306356 oh come on...it's not *that* bad. I've given worse translations on this site.

Comment: Haha, well it was "the gloom," that really got me.